# Loads of errors upgrading from mvc 3.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to upgrade a old project of mine from 3.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.1 and its giving me over 100 errors

eg.
The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
The name 'T' does not exist in the current context
etc etc

Heres my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please   visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
-->
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="routeMapping" type="flubes.Configuration.Routing.RouteMappingConfiguration, flubes" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="site" type="flubes.Configuration.SiteConfiguration, flubes" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="redirector" type="flubes.Configuration.Redirector.RedirectorConfiguration, flubes" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="integration" type="flubes.Configuration.Integration.IntegrationConfiguration, flubes" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<routeMapping configSource="Config\Routes.config" />
<site configSource="Config\Site.config" />
<redirector configSource="Config\Redirector.config" />
<integration configSource="Config\Integration.config" />
<nlog configSource="Config\Logging.config" />
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Forums" connectionString="Data Source=ADAM\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial   Catalog=forums;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx;Integrated Security=TRuE;" />
    <add name="Membership" connectionString="Data   Source=ADAM\MSSQLSERVER2;Initial Catalog=forums;User   ID=sa;Password=xxxx;Integrated Security=TRUE;" />
    <!--    <add name="YourDb" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT2008;User   ID=sa;Password=12345678" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    The above connectionstring with name "forums" will be used by the site.
    Below this line you can see 2 samples of connection strings, one that    points to a Microsoft SQL Server database and other that points to a MySql   database.
    <add name="ForumsMSSQL" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial   Catalog=Forums;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ForumsMySql" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=forums;Uid=user;Pwd=12345678;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
-->
</connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        <add invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<!--
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory"  from="admin@yoursite.com">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
-->
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ForumsMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="ForumsMembershipProvider"   type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"  connectionStringName="Membership" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="30" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="flubes" />
<!--
            <add name="ForumsMembershipProvider"
                 type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral"
                 connectionStringName="Forums" 
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="30" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="flubes"/>
-->
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />
        <add verb="*" path="*" type="flubes.Web.Handlers.StaticFileHandler,   flubes.Web" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="RedirectorModule" type="flubes.Web.Modules.RedirectorModule, flubes.Web" />
        <add name="ModelBinderModule" type="flubes.Web.Modules.ModelBinderModule, flubes.Web" />
        <add name="CompressionModule" type="flubes.Web.Modules.CompressionModule, flubes.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
<!-- 
IIS 7.0.  or above
-->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="RedirectorModule" type="flubes.Web.Modules.RedirectorModule, flubes.Web" />
        <add name="ModelBinderModule" type="flubes.Web.Modules.ModelBinderModule, flubes.Web" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
   </configuration>
```

Heres the views/web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="flubes.Web.UI.BaseViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="flubes"/>
            <add namespace="flubes.Dto"/>
            <add namespace="flubes.Validation"/>
            <add namespace="flubes.Configuration"/>
            <add namespace="flubes.Web.Extensions"/>
            <add namespace="System.Security"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter,  System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
        <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio works great for managing projects for most tasks, but upgrading dependencies is where things frequently go wrong. Quite often, you need to do manual intervention by editing the `.csproj` file directly.

First of all, save all of the work in your solution that you want to save. Then right click on your MVC project in Solution Explorer, and click "Unload Project". This will leave only a single node for the project, followed by `(unavailable)`. Right-click on that node and choose `Edit XXX.csproj`, where XXX is your project name. Click OK on any dialogs that pop up. This will open an XML view of the `.csproj` file (which is actually an MSBuild file). Scroll down the file and look for your references to `System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.Razor`, and `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` are correct and *make sure there are no duplicate `Reference`entries*. If configured correctly, it should look something like the following.

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.4.0.20715.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Do note that the above example is for .NET framework 4.0. To target another framework version, you should change the `\net40\` segment to the closest version that exists in your packages folder. Also, you should always check to ensure there is a file at the location specified in the `HintPath`.

When you have finished, save the file and then right-click the project node in Solution Explorer, and click `Reload Project`.

If your project has dependent projects that reference MVC, you should repeat the same procedure for all of them.

If your project has dependent DLLs that reference MVC, first try to get a version that references the *correct* version of MVC. If one doesn't exist, then use [binding redirects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure that all of your dependent DLLs use the same MVC version.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

> NOTE: If you are using other features of MVC, there may be more references and binding redirects to update than what is listed above. The easiest way to find out what versions you need is to create a new MVC 4 project, add the same references (new version) to the new project, and then analyze the `.csproj` and web.config files to bring over the correct configuration to the project that you are upgrading.

Of course, you also need to check and upgrade the references in your web.config file anywhere there is a version involved, but you apparently have already done that step.